# Blank Page after gulp serve:dist

Tags: javascript, angularjs, generator-gulp-angular

I'm using the Swiip/generator-gulp-angular generator in my project. Everything works like a charm when I execute *gulp serve*, but when I execute *gulp serve:dist*, I get this error:

> vendor.js:13842 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module prometheus due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   Failed to instantiate module ngStorage due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=ngStorage
>       at http://localhost:3000/scripts/vendor-7ba12c98b6.js:31:376 ...

I actually don't have a clue about this.

**NOTE** 
I already took a look at this issue: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/715

inject.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var _ = require('lodash');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('inject-reload', ['inject'], function() {
  browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('inject', ['scripts', 'styles'], function () {
  var injectStyles = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.css'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/vendor.css')
  ], { read: false });

  var injectScripts = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.spec.js'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.mock.js'),
  ])
  .pipe($.angularFilesort()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('AngularFilesort'));

  var injectOptions = {
    ignorePath: [conf.paths.src, path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')],
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, injectOptions))
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
});
```

build.js

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

gulp.task('partials', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.html'),
    path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/**/*.html')
  ])
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
      module: 'prometheus',
      root: 'app'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.tmp + '/partials/'));
});

gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
  var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });
  var partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/partials'),
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html', { restore: true });
  var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css', { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
    .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
    .pipe($.cssnano())
    .pipe($.rev())
    // .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true
    }))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')))
    .pipe($.size({ title: path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), showFiles: true }));
  });

// Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
// Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,otf,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});

gulp.task('other', function () {
  var fileFilter = $.filter(function (file) {
    return file.stat.isFile();
  });

  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*'),
    path.join('!' + conf.paths.src, '/**/*.{html,css,js,less}')
  ])
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/')));
});

gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return $.del([path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/'), path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/')]);
});

gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'other']);
```

Comment: can you put snippets of your gulp file

Comment: sure, just edited the question to add them